# Must a husband and wife make separate online applications for a UK Standard Visitor visa, and so attend separate appointments for biometrics?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, family

My wife and I are both applying for a UK Standard Visitor visa.

Do we need to fill the visa application form at visa4uk **separately**?

That would mean we will have to go for biometric appointments separately.

Is that how it works?

Comment: Yes, each person completes their own application, but depending upon availability you may be able to enrol your biometrics at the same time.

Comment: @GayotFow that should be an answer not a comment.

Comment: @chx Fair enough, taken as read.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Each person (including children) needs to file a separate application. Based upon your text, the recommended strategy is...

1. Your wife applies first and records her GWF number.  She schedules
   her biometrics enrolment on a day that appears totally open.
2. You apply second and put your wife's GWF number in the remarks
   section of the application and explain that you are travelling
   together.

If you cannot schedule biometrics at the same time, make two different appointments but *show up together* and ask if they can accommodate you. No guarantees, but sometimes it works.

Note: only the primary needs to submit financial evidence. This is pointed out in the [Supporting Documents Guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents).

> if you are applying as a family/group you do not need to provide
>   multiple copies of the same documents

Comment: Thanks for clearing up my confusion. we went separately. Although they said they allow husband and wife to come together even if their appointment times are different.

Comment: @Jitesh on behalf of the community, allow me to thank you for getting back to us with a confirmation. Ask more new questions when they arise.

Comment: For VFS Dubai / Abu Dhabi, try to get all appointment on the same day. I paid separate charges to shift my son's appointment day to be on the same day as of mother. Otherwise, they were asking to come again on my Son's appointment time and submit all documents again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply separately at GOV.UK or VISFORUK.ORG and after you're done you register and make an appointment on the visa center's website depending on which country you're from. At that point use both GWF numbers to register for a group appointment, they will have that option on the center's website.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But the group appointment is available for additional 160 euros. Is there any other way?