# Can I apply multiple UK Visas under one account?

Tags: visas, standard-visitor-visas, tourist-visas

I'm using the visa4uk.fco.gov.uk to apply for a UK VISA for myself, my wife and two sons. I assume that I have to fill out separate applications for each of us. Can I just fill out all the applications under one account using the "Apply for Myself" and "Apply for someone else" feature where I would fill out details for my family?

Comment: Make a new account for each applicant.  I don't get the "b1-b2" tag however.

Comment: @GayotFow What's the "Apply for Someone Else" feature exactly for? While paying the fees and printing all the applications, it would be pretty messed up by logging in to everyone one by one. Secondly, how do they know it's a family application if we have made separate accounts? Wouldn't it be easy and a good-practice to see family applications together?

Comment: The 4th rule of thermodynamics regarding the conservation of keystrokes does not apply in this instance, and somehow people manage to cope with it. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64893/separate-visa-for-husband-and-wife-for-uk-visitor-visa  for 'best practices'.  Also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51582/how-should-a-family-with-young-children-apply-for-uk-visas/51592#51592